# my php code doesn't validate data with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html

I hav a Php code. It connects with the server and database, but it does not validate my form data with mysql database table. I hav same exact code which executes, but the following does not execute.........

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
    header("Location: welcome.html");
}

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['loginName'];
    $upass = $_POST['loginPass'];
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM authen WHERE name='$name'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);

    if($row['passwrd']==$upass)
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
        header("Location: welcome.html");
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>alert('wrong details');</script>
        <?php
    }

}
?>
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <!-- JavaScript includes
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.fancybox.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="formContainer">
            <form id="login" method="post">
                <p id="lgnfrm">Login Form</p>
                <input type="text" name="loginName" id="loginName" placeholder="User Name" required />
                <input type="password" name="loginPass" id="loginPass" placeholder="password" required  />
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="sub" value="Login" />
            </form>
        </div>

        <footer>

        </footer>



    </body>
</html>
```

I hav modified the code as directed but still i get the same response, i.e nothing happens

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != "")
{
    header("Location: welcome.html");
}

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['loginName']);
    $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['loginPass']);
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM authen WHERE name='$name'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);

    if($row['passwrd']==md5($upass))
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
        header("Location: welcome.html");
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>alert('wrong details');</script>
        <?php
    }

}
?>
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <!-- JavaScript includes
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.fancybox.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="formContainer">
            <form id="login" method="post">
                <p id="lgnfrm">Login Form</p>
                <input type="text" name="loginName" id="loginName" placeholder="User Name" required />
                <input type="password" name="loginPass" id="loginPass" placeholder="password" required  />
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="sub" value="Login" />
            </form>
        </div>

        <footer>

        </footer>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: isset() returns true or false. Comparing it to "" will return false everytime. The user will be redirected to welcome, even if he isnt logged in.

Comment: What do you mean by does not execute? Did you check the web server log?

Comment: First `mysql_*` functions are no longer supported by PHP anymore try using `mysqli_*` functions or PDO. Second you are using data as it is from form input to query Huge security risk (try using prepared statements). Third storing password as plain text in database is not safe. and finally need more description of the problem, what are the error is any (not working is not a problem description)

Comment: [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) returns boolean your code should be something like.. `if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] !="")`

Comment: it doesn't show any errors, when i press submit nothing happens @bansi

Comment: when i give mysqli_*, it shows access denied

Comment: move the `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC......` line to just above `<html  xmlns="html.....` line. or for better result try using [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php). `header` wont work if there is some output already started.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys................ I've found the soln......

Comment: There was an id conflict. I dont thnk that would be the reason. Since my problem is solved it doesnt mater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isset returns boolean

your code should be

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != "")
{
    header("Location: welcome.html");
    exit;
}
```

Or

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("Location: welcome.html");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Not that I disagree with your suggestion but in php remember `false == ''` is true

Comment: There should be `exit` statements after the header redirects.

Answer (score -1):

Do following changes in your first code

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && !empty($_SESSION['user']))
{
header("Location: welcome.html");
}
```

hope this helps!!,please comment for further queries

Comment: removing the quotes around string arguments will return an error and leave the SQL further open to compromise. This is not a solution.

Comment: Sory to say. My code had nothng to do with the above solutions. It was id conflict....... Do u think html element id's hav anythng to do with php execution @VikasBhandari

Comment: What was conflict...can you elaborate? @Elson